# Are my Greasemonkey scripts visible outside my PC?

Tags: javascript, security, passwords, greasemonkey

Forgive me if this is a dumb question. I'm not familiar with how browser scripts are handled.

I'm writing a short Greasemonkey script that involves auto-logging me into a website, which of course involves inserting my password. I was planning to just include my password in the script itself, but I'm concerned that if it's possible for anyone else to see my script, they will also see my password.

So my question is, is it possible for my script to be seen by anyone/anything beyond my browser and local PC? I'm not talking about anyone else using my computer, but anyone "probing" or otherwise inspecting my browser from elsewhere on the net.

If so, how can I store my password so it can be auto-inserted without sacrificing my security?

Comment: https://lastpass.com/?

Comment: Storing your passwords in plaintext anywhere is generally not a good idea, even if no one can see it.

Comment: @user113215 Could a Lastpass password be inserted via javascript?

Comment: The LastPass browser plugin automatically fills in `<input type="password">` fields after seeing the form once. It ignores HTML markup directing the browser not to remember passwords. I'm not sure about scripting LastPass manually.

Answer (score 2):

Nominally, no. Greasemonkey scripts are not any more visible outside your PC than any other unencrypted file on your hard drive.

That said, there are several things to keep in mind:

1. **Use a password utility instead.**
   Use trusted utilities that are designed to work-with and secure passwords as much as possible.  As mentioned, [*LastPass*](https://lastpass.com/) is pretty popular.  I have also used [*Secure Login*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/secure-login/) to good effect.

   Admittedly, these utilities do not work for every situation, since so many sites insist on their own variations of a login page/system.  So, I personally do use Greasemonkey scripts to log into a few low-risk websites.
2. **Never use an auto-login for sensitive sites.**
   If you use a script for a bank, credit-card, important work database, etc.  Somebody *will* be sitting at your computer some day and they *will* visit that site (and be automatically logged in), and bad things *will* happen.  Bank on it.
   Now, I know that some will (foolishly) ignore this.  But, if you do, at least have the login triggered by a hotkey or hotkey sequence -- never fully automatic.
3. **Beware `unsafeWindow`.**
   Greasemonkey scripts used to be vulnerable to an exploit against [`unsafeWindow`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow).  While I *believe* that this vulnerability was closed by Firefox version 4 (The old exploit recipe certainly does not work with modern GM+FF), an `unsafeWindow` exploit would allow a compromised web page to see parts of your script source and to use `GM_` functions.

   So, for login scripts especially, don't use `unsafeWindow`.
4. **Never include a real password in *any* source file.**
   Don't make it so easy for prying eyes or malware to get your password!  This has been an easy route to pwn-dom for decades, and yet people still get burned by this -- probably every day.
5. **Don't store passwords in clear text.** and don't use "password" and "username", for variable names.
   This won't stop a determined bad guy, but it will slow down "honest" snoops and script-kiddies.

Here is the Greasemonkey script framework I use on the two pages where I automatically login (both are forums, low-risk, low sensitivity).

The username and password are stored in the browser prefs database (visible via `about:config`), not the script source.  They are lightly encrypted to slow down snoops.

The first time you run the script, it will prompt for a random key and for the username and password.  After that, the username and password can be changed via the Greasemonkey context menu.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Autologin, sensitive info framework
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/sjcl.js
// @grant    GM_getValue
// @grant    GM_setValue
// @grant    GM_registerMenuCommand
// ==/UserScript==

var encKey  = GM_getValue ("encKey",  "");
var usr     = GM_getValue ("lognUsr", "");
var pword   = GM_getValue ("lognPwd", "");

if ( ! encKey) {
    encKey  = prompt (
        'Script key not set for ' + location.hostname + '. Please enter a random string:',
        ''
    );
    GM_setValue ("encKey", encKey);

    usr     = pword = "";   // New key makes prev stored values (if any) unable to decode.
}
usr         = decodeOrPrompt (usr,   "U-name", "lognUsr");
pword       = decodeOrPrompt (pword, "P-word", "lognPwd");


function decodeOrPrompt (targVar, userPrompt, setValVarName) {
    if (targVar) {
        targVar     = unStoreAndDecrypt (targVar);
    }
    else {
        targVar     = prompt (
            userPrompt + ' not set for ' + location.hostname + '. Please enter it now:',
            ''
        );
        GM_setValue (setValVarName, encryptAndStore (targVar) );
    }
    return targVar;
}

function encryptAndStore (clearText) {
    return  JSON.stringify (sjcl.encrypt (encKey, clearText) );
}

function unStoreAndDecrypt (jsonObj) {
    return  sjcl.decrypt (encKey, JSON.parse (jsonObj) );
}

//-- Add menu commands that will allow U and P to be changed.
GM_registerMenuCommand ("Change Username", changeUsername);
GM_registerMenuCommand ("Change Password", changePassword);

function changeUsername () {
    promptAndChangeStoredValue (usr,   "U-name", "lognUsr");
}

function changePassword () {
    promptAndChangeStoredValue (pword, "P-word", "lognPwd");
}

function promptAndChangeStoredValue (targVar, userPrompt, setValVarName) {
    targVar     = prompt (
        'Change ' + userPrompt + ' for ' + location.hostname + ':',
        targVar
    );
    GM_setValue (setValVarName, encryptAndStore (targVar) );
}

/*-- These next 3 lines are for debug / edification.  
Remove or comment out of the final script.
*/
console.log ("Script start.");
console.log ("usr: ",   usr);
console.log ("pword: ", pword);

// ADD YOUR CODE TO SET THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD ON THE LOGIN PAGE, HERE.
```

Comment: Are you console.log-ging the user and password in plain there?

Comment: @JonasWielicki: Yes, but that's just for debug/educational purposes for this post.

Answer (score -1):

yes they are!! With an event listener on the event `DOMNodeInserted` of a script by the requested site your source code (and by that your password)  is visible by ALL the scripts on the requested site.

Have a look [here](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Security_Hole_.231:_Source_Code_Leakage) for further information.

Comment: That applied to Greasemonkey 0.3, and earlier, and was fixed over 12 years ago.